# Double Dreadful Diamond Inheritance issue (alternative solutions allowed)

Tags: c++, architecture, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I ended up in a situation lined out below.

I have one library that is pure CPP without external libraries, and another project that is an SDK to interface with an external library.

[image: Double Dreadful Diamond issue]

"I" in front of the name indicates an abstract class. Arrows indicate inheritance.

I have IDevice which contains HandleInput(data) as a callback, and StartDevice().
Then I have a more specific type of device: ISmartwatch (containing StartTimer), and from that inherits a more specific version SmartwatchV1, which implements HandleInput(data) according to its needs.

That all seemed great until I came to the external SDK part, where the library expects me to use inheritance to interface with it to override some functions. So, I have to inherit from the external library, and from my own CPP library, to override the functions I need. Most of these library overrides suit any device (IExternalLibDevice), but a few are specific to the exact Stopwatch version (ExternallSmartWatchV1).

Then for polymorphism in my SDK, I would like to call and override functions both provided by the library and my own device example: libDevice.StartDevice() and use library calls within this optionally overriden StartDevice. Or stopWatch.StartTimer(), stopwatchV1.libraryOverride().
The object which I need to create is the green one, however, the white SmartWatchV1 is also an object to instantiate in applications without the library. (And obviously I keep in mind any future alternative devices or stopwatch versions.)

I think if I drop any inheritance arrow, I would either lose out on polymorphism (so SDK code will only work for a very specific smartwatch version), or I cannot override functions I need anymore. Composition would be nice, but won't work for overriding functions, or is there an option I don't know about?

And so, I ended up here. I am encountering quite some annoying errors implementing this, since double diamond is usually solved with virtual inheritance (nice page about double diamond: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#mi-diamond). However, when applied here (see the v's that indicate "virtual" in the image), I have one inheritance that should both be virtual and not be virtual. Additionally, virtual inheritance makes constructors really annoying in my generic CPP library. Even without virtual (which as far as I'm aware would cause some duplication of classes in memory and a lot of ambiguity to solve), I have some constructor errors ("no suitable default constructor" for a class that must not have a default constructor, etc) issues.

I have been battling to solve this for a long time, and I hope someone more experienced can make a suggestion that provides a better solution for my code structure or issue.

Comment: Why do you need an internal inheritance hierarchy? Or is that just a separate library?

Comment: @PasserBy In the Self-Made SDK (self-written btw) it is for two reasons: For some functions in the IExternalLibClass that I have to override,  some are suitable for any device (Connect for example)), and others are very specific to the Stopwatch (SendTimeToCalendar). So, inheriting is better, since importing the ExternalLibClass to all things separately would support fewer devices and would cause more doubling of override code.

Comment: Thereby also within the SDK part, I like to use polymorphism as well as much as possible, so the code I write will work for as many devices as possible (including code with library use).

Comment: I can't tell entirely from your description, but dropping the internal inheritance hierarchy and having a member `SmartwatchV1` in the external class which forwards function calls sounds viable.

Comment: @PasserBy, thanks for thinking with me, one thing that would be unhandy is that I would have to implement all the same things for the library (copy lots of code) for slight different versions of smartwatch (an extra button, not reading out the date, also some groups smartwatches receiving stuff from the library, etc). That would be really inconvenient, since we have a lot of versions. So at least implementing it generically (also for other devices), would have my preference. Or is there a way to do that with what you suggest?

Comment: You can have template classes inherit from the same interface, if that's what you want, e.g. `template<typename T> class derived : base {};`

Comment: @PasserBy I have a hard time getting my head around what would be the best part of my diagram to implement with that template (I am quite new to using them, and don't completely see how they make sense here). Could you give me some example with names of the scheme that could be in the template and what base would be? Then hopefully I can better understand what you mean

Comment: I struggled to make the SDK part with templates today as you indicated, however, I just realized even if I manage to do that, it would not work since the external library (not self-written) internally calls and uses my object, so it would not be able to understand the proper Template type if it receives it. I'm currently giving up on making the SDK part anywhere near nicely organised/creating general device code that is nicely reused but just making a completely new library per Smartwatch version (copied code). If you have any more ideas, I'd love to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I solved it by using composition:

- Add an IDevice pointer to IExternalLibDevice that is set in the constructor.
- In IExternalLibSmartwatch: add an ISmartwatch pointer to the constructor and pass it to its parent constructor. Also, add a function that retrieves the IDevice pointer as an ISmartwatch.
- In ExternalSmartwatchV1: also add a SmartwatchV1 to the constructor and pass it to its parent constructor, and create a function that retrieves the IDevice pointer as a SmartwatchV1.

The IDevice pointer holds the reference to the cppLibDevice, and can now be cast to any of the subclasses it belongs to. Downside: I cannot override the cpp lib classes, but it was not a hard requirement for my code, since I created alternative functions in the ExternalLib classes that can optionally call the cppLibDevice functions, or completely replace them.